# How is Bootstrap's `nav` class making anchors move to their own line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out what CSS is causing `a` elements to sit on their own lines when they have Bootstrap's `nav` class, when I can't find any meaningful difference in the styles applied to them vs. `a` elements without `nav`. I've looked at the rules applied and even compared the computed styles, and I'm not seeing anything to explain it.

Here's an example: The `a` in the first paragraph (with the `nav` class) sits on its own line, whereas the `a` in the second doesn't:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>before <a id="a1" class="nav" href="#">link</a> after</p>
<p>before <a id="a2"             href="#">link</a> after</p>
```

If I inspect the `a.nav` element, I see this rule is applied:

```
.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

...but I don't see how that causes it to sit on its own line. So I wrote some code to compare the computed styles of the two `a` elements in the example above, in case I was somehow magically missing some other rule. Doesn't look like it; their computed styles are identical other than `list-style-type` (and therefore `list-style`):

```js
(function() {
  var s1 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a1")),
      s2 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a2")),
      diffs = {};

  function logDifferences(prop) {
    var s1value = s1[prop],
        s2value = s2[prop];
    if (prop != "cssText" && s1value !== s2value) {
      diffs[prop] = {
        s1: s1value,
        s2: s2value
      }
    }
  }

  Object.keys(s1).forEach(logDifferences);
  Object.keys(s2).forEach(logDifferences);
  Object.keys(diffs).sort().forEach(function(prop) {
    var diff = diffs[prop];
    display(prop + ": '" + diff.s1 + "' != '" + diff.s2 + "'")
  });

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>before <a id="a1" class="nav" href="#">link</a> after</p>
<p>before <a id="a2"             href="#">link</a> after</p>
```

`list-style-type` shouldn't cause this behavior, and indeed if I overrule that I still get the behavior, with the computed styles of the elements being identical:

```js
(function() {
  var s1 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a1")),
      s2 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("a2")),
      diffs = {};

  function logDifferences(prop) {
    var s1value = s1[prop],
        s2value = s2[prop];
    if (prop != "cssText" && s1value !== s2value) {
      diffs[prop] = {
        s1: s1value,
        s2: s2value
      }
    }
  }

  Object.keys(s1).forEach(logDifferences);
  Object.keys(s2).forEach(logDifferences);
  Object.keys(diffs).sort().forEach(function(prop) {
    var diff = diffs[prop];
    display(prop + ": '" + diff.s1 + "' != '" + diff.s2 + "'")
  });

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

```css
a.nav {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>before <a id="a1" class="nav" href="#">link</a> after</p>
<p>before <a id="a2"             href="#">link</a> after</p>
```

So it's not the `list-style-type`.

Nor is it the order of the elements:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>before <a id="a2"             href="#">link</a> after</p>
<p>before <a id="a1" class="nav" href="#">link</a> after</p>
```

What is it that's causing the `a.nav` to move to its own line?

Note that the question isn't how to fix it. We've already fixed it (they shouldn't have `nav`, we were using that for something else before we applied Bootstrap to the project and we've just renamed ours so Bootstrap's rules don't get incorrectly applied). The question is what's causing it?

Comment: Moral: If you can't see a difference in the elements, think *pseudo-elements*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. They're specifically set up to *clear* any floated elements surrounding them, but a side affect of this is that they also cause the element itself to be pushed down to a new line.

[image: Example]

The offending style is quite simply:

```css
...::before, ...::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
```

<sup>*Where ... here is a long chain of selectors including `.nav::after` and `.nav::before`.*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The rule you're looking for is the quite lengthy

```
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::before, .btn-toolbar::after, .btn-toolbar::before, .clearfix::after, .clearfix::before, .container-fluid::after, .container-fluid::before, .container::after, .container::before, .dl-horizontal dd::after, .dl-horizontal dd::before, .form-horizontal .form-group::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::before, .modal-footer::after, .modal-footer::before, .nav::after, .nav::before, .navbar-collapse::after, .navbar-collapse::before, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-header::before, .navbar::after, .navbar::before, .pager::after, .pager::before, .panel-body::after, .panel-body::before, .row::after, .row::before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: ...and of course, comparing the computed styles of the elements won't tell me anything about the computed styles of the associated **pseudo** elements. I should have realized.

Answer (score 1):

if you inspect the element further down you'll find that `.nav:after` and `nav.before` have `display: table` that's why it sits in its own line

```
.btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:after, .btn-group-vertical>.btn-group:before,
.btn-toolbar:after, .btn-toolbar:before, .clearfix:after, .clearfix:before,
.container-fluid:after, .container-fluid:before, .container:after, 
.container:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after, .dl-horizontal dd:before, 
.form-horizontal .form-group:after, .form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.modal-footer:after, .modal-footer:before, .nav:after, .nav:before, 
.navbar-collapse:after, .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-header:after, 
.navbar-header:before, .navbar:after, .navbar:before, .pager:after, 
.pager:before, .panel-body:after, .panel-body:before, .row:after, 
.row:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```